Loading screen when the chromecastButton is created
I am using better_player and flutter_cast_video packages.
When I play a video, the chromecast button is created, if I click on the screen so that it and the other controls disappear and I press again so that they appear, the chromecast button is created again. Along with this creation, a loading screen of the same chromecast appears for a few milliseconds.
I need to solve that problem, I have searched the internal code of the flutter_cast_video package and I can't find anything that solves it either.
Here I leave the respective code for the screen that plays the video
class VideoPlayerScreenValue extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  BetterPlayerController? _betterPlayerPlusController;
  bool areButtonsVisible = true;
  ValueNotifier<bool> areControlsVisible = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);
  ValueNotifier<bool> isPlayingNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);
  ValueNotifier<bool> controllerActive = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
  ValueNotifier<Duration> actualSecond = ValueNotifier<Duration>(Duration.zero);
  ChromeCastController? _controller;

  // Este ValueNotifier mantendrá el estado de reproducción del video
  ValueNotifier<bool> isPlaying = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);

// Estas funciones se llamarán cuando se presionen los botones de salto
  void seekForward() {
    if (controllerActive.value) {
      _controller!.seek(interval: 10, relative: true);
    } else {
      _betterPlayerPlusController!.seekTo(
          _betterPlayerPlusController!.videoPlayerController!.value.position +
              const Duration(seconds: 10));
    }
  }

  void seekBackward() {
    if (controllerActive.value) {
      _controller!.seek(interval: -10, relative: true);
    } else {
      _betterPlayerPlusController!.seekTo(
          _betterPlayerPlusController!.videoPlayerController!.value.position -
              const Duration(seconds: 10));
    }
  }

//Initialize the player
  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
    if (widget.videoUrl.isNotEmpty) {
      super.initState();
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
          [DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight, DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
      _betterPlayerPlusController = BetterPlayerController(
        _betterPlayerConfiguration(),
      );

      initPlayer();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.videoUrl.isEmpty) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text(
          'No video available',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      );
    }
    return _vpControls();
  }

  String _formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    final minutes = duration.inMinutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final seconds = (duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return '$minutes:$seconds';
  }

  Widget _vpControls() {
    return Material(
      type: MaterialType.transparency,
      child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
        valueListenable: areControlsVisible,
        builder: (context, isVisible, child) {
          return Stack(children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: _toggleControls,
              child: BetterPlayer(
                controller: _betterPlayerPlusController!,
              ),
            ),
            if (isVisible) ...[
              Positioned(
                top: 25,
                left: 0,
                child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                  valueListenable: isPlayingNotifier,
                  builder: (context, value, child) {
                    return Visibility(
                      visible: value,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 45,
                right: 0,
                child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                  valueListenable: areControlsVisible,
                  builder: (context, isVisible, child) {
                    return Visibility(
                      visible: isVisible,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0, right: 10),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width:
                              50, // Ajusta estos valores al tamaño que desees
                          height: 50,
                          child: _chromeCastButton(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 50,
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.fast_rewind,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 33,
                  ),
                  onPressed: seekBackward,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 50,
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.fast_forward,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 33,
                  ),
                  onPressed: seekForward,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
                right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                  valueListenable: isPlaying,
                  builder: (context, value, child) {
                    return IconButton(
                      icon: value
                          ? const Icon(
                              Icons.pause,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 33,
                            )
                          : const Icon(
                              Icons.play_arrow,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 33,
                            ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (value) {
                          if (controllerActive.value) {
                            _controller!.pause();
                          } else {
                            _betterPlayerPlusController!.pause();
                          }
                        } else {
                          if (controllerActive.value) {
                            _controller!.play();
                          } else {
                            _betterPlayerPlusController!.play();
                          }
                        }
                        // Aquí cambiamos el valor de isPlaying cuando se presiona el botón
                        isPlaying.value = !value;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 33,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: ValueListenableBuilder<Duration>(
                  valueListenable: actualSecond,
                  builder: (context, value, child) {
                    final totalDuration = _betterPlayerPlusController!
                            .videoPlayerController!.value.duration ??
                        Duration.zero;
                    return Slider(
                      value: value.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      min: 0.0,
                      max: totalDuration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      onChanged: (double newValue) {
                        if (controllerActive.value) {
                          print("Tiempo 1");
                          _controller!
                              .seek(interval: newValue, relative: false);
                        } else {
                          print(2);
                          _betterPlayerPlusController!
                              .seekTo(Duration(seconds: newValue.toInt()));
                          actualSecond.value =
                              Duration(seconds: newValue.toInt());
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 10,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: ValueListenableBuilder<Duration>(
                  valueListenable: actualSecond,
                  builder: (context, value, child) {
                    final totalDuration = _betterPlayerPlusController!
                            .videoPlayerController!.value.duration ??
                        Duration.zero;
                    return Text(
                      '${_formatDuration(value)} / ${_formatDuration(totalDuration)}',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]
          ]);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Timer? _hideControlsTimer;

  void _toggleControls() {
    if (areControlsVisible.value) {
      areControlsVisible.value = false;
      _hideControlsTimer?.cancel();
    } else {
      areControlsVisible.value = true;

      _hideControlsTimer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
        if (areControlsVisible.value) {
          areControlsVisible.value = false;
        }
      });
    }
  }

//Configuration of Better Player
  BetterPlayerConfiguration _betterPlayerConfiguration() {
    return BetterPlayerConfiguration(
      autoDispose: true,
      startAt: widget.startAt,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      subtitlesConfiguration: _betterPlayerSubtitlesConfiguration(),
      allowedScreenSleep: false,
      autoDetectFullscreenDeviceOrientation: false,
      deviceOrientationsOnFullScreen: [
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft
      ],
      errorBuilder: (context, message) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            message!,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      },
      autoPlay: true,
      controlsConfiguration: _betterPlayerControlsConfiguration(),
    );
  }

//Configuration of Better Player Subtitles
  BetterPlayerSubtitlesConfiguration _betterPlayerSubtitlesConfiguration() {
    return const BetterPlayerSubtitlesConfiguration(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      fontSize: 20,
      fontColor: Colors.white,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    );
  }

//Configuration of Better Player Controls Configuration
  BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration _betterPlayerControlsConfiguration() {
    return const BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(
      //fullscreenEnableIcon: Icons.fullscreen_exit,
      enableSkips: false,
      showControls: false,
      enableOverflowMenu: false,
      enablePlayPause: false,
      enableFullscreen: false,
      enableMute: false,
      enableSubtitles: false,
      enableProgressBar: false,

      textColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
      iconsColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
    );
  }

//Configuration of the dataSource
  Future<void> initPlayer() async {
    BetterPlayerDataSource betterPlayerPlusDataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
      BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
      widget.videoUrl,
    );

    _betterPlayerPlusController!.setupDataSource(betterPlayerPlusDataSource);

    _betterPlayerPlusController!.addEventsListener((event) {
      // Close the player when the video is finished
      if (event.betterPlayerEventType == BetterPlayerEventType.finished) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    });

    // Add a listener to the video player controller
    _betterPlayerPlusController!.videoPlayerController!.addListener(() {
      // Update the actualSecond value with the current position of the video
      actualSecond.value =
          _betterPlayerPlusController!.videoPlayerController!.value.position;
    });
// Start a timer to hide the controls after 2 seconds
    _hideControlsTimer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      if (areControlsVisible.value) {
        areControlsVisible.value = false;
      }
    });
  }

//Dispose the player
  @override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top, SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    if (widget.videoUrl.isNotEmpty) {
      saveLastPosition();
    }
    _betterPlayerPlusController!.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    _controller?.removeSessionListener();
    _hideControlsTimer?.cancel();

    super.dispose();
  }

//Save the last position of the video
  Future<void> saveLastPosition() async {
    Dio dio = Dio();
    Duration? lastPosition =
        _betterPlayerPlusController!.videoPlayerController?.value.position;

    int lastSecond = lastPosition!.inSeconds;

    String jsonData = jsonEncode({
      'content': widget.content,
      'resource': widget.id,
      'second': lastSecond,
    });

    await dio.post(
      'https://${Environment.KEY_URL}/api/1.0/seconds_view/',
      options: Options(
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer ${Environment.DIO_TOKEN}",
        },
      ),
      data: jsonData,
    );
  }

  //! ********************* CHROME CAST ********************* !//

  //This widget is used to show the chromecast button

  Widget _chromeCastButton() {
    return ChromeCastButton(
      onButtonCreated: (controller) {
        if (_controller == null) {
          _controller = controller;
          _controller!.addSessionListener();
        }
      },
      onSessionStarted: _onSessionStarted,
      onRequestCompleted: _onRequestCompleted,
      onSessionEnded: onSessionEnded,
      onRequestFailed: (String? error) async {
        _controller!.endSession();
      },
      onPlayerStatusUpdated: (int statusCode) {
        // Aquí puedes manejar las actualizaciones de estado del reproductor
        print('Player status updated: $statusCode');
      },
    );
  }

  void onSessionEnded() async {
    print("Session ended");
    controllerActive.value = false;
    _controller!.removeSessionListener();
    _controller!.endSession(); // End the session when it's ended
    _controller!.addSessionListener();
  }

  //Cuando se completa la solicitud y aparece el video
  void _onRequestCompleted() async {
    if (actualSecond.value != Duration.zero) {
      _controller!.seek(
          interval: actualSecond.value.inSeconds.toDouble(), relative: true);
      actualSecond.value = Duration.zero;
    }
  }

  //Antes de que aparezca el video, mientras se carga

  void _onSessionStarted() async {
    controllerActive.value = true;
    _betterPlayerPlusController!.pause();
    await _controller!.loadMedia(
      widget.videoUrl.isNotEmpty ? widget.videoUrl : "",
      title: widget.name,
      subtitle: widget.description,
    );
    actualSecond.value =
        _betterPlayerPlusController!.videoPlayerController!.value.position;

    // Show a notification when the video is playing on Chromecast
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id',
      'your channel name',
      playSound: false,
      enableVibration: false,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      actions: <AndroidNotificationAction>[
        AndroidNotificationAction('stop', 'Stop'),
      ],
    );

    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'Video is playing on Chromecast',
      'Tap Stop to stop the video',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
    );
  }

  Timer? _timer;
  Duration? position, duration;

  //This function is used to monitor the chromecast
  Future<void> _monitor() async {
    // monitor cast events
    Duration dur = await _controller!.duration(),
        pos = await _controller!.position();
    if (duration == null || duration!.inSeconds != dur.inSeconds) {
      setState(() {
        duration = dur;
      });
    }
    if (position == null || position!.inSeconds != pos.inSeconds) {
      setState(() {
        position = pos;
      });
    }
  }

  //This function is used to reset the timer
  void resetTimer() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = null;
  }

  //This function is used to start the timer
  void startTimer() {
    if (_timer?.isActive ?? false) {
      return;
    }
    resetTimer();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      _monitor();
    });
  }

I want that loading screen to stop appearing
